# Potencial recursivo

Tags: java, funciones, recursión

buenos días. Estoy realizando lo siguiente:
Un programa que calcule la potencia de un número, a este programa le pasamos tanto la base como el exponente y tiene que calcularlo de manera recursiva.
Mi codigo:

```
package recursividad;

import java.util.*;

public class potencialRecursivo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int base, exp;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("\tPrograma que calcula la potencia de un numero");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------");

        System.out.print("Introduzca la base: ");
        base = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Introduzca el exponente: ");
        exp = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("La potencia de " + base + " elevado a " + exp + " es: " + potencia(exp, base));
    }

    public static int potencia(int exp, int base) {
        int sol;
        if (exp == 1) {
            sol = base;
        } else {
            sol = base * potencia(base, (exp - 1));
            return sol;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Mi problema es que solo me retorna "0" imagino que esto será por el "return 0" del metodo "potencia" pero si quito ese return me da error el programa.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Ese `return 0` debería ser `return sol` (el cual por tanto sobra del `else`)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, sabía que tenía que ser alguna cosa así la que me estaba fallando.
De hecho el return sol sabía que iba fuera del else pero, error de novato, lo puse dentro.

Comment: No estaba del todo mal dentro, el gran problema era cuando la recursión llegaba al caso `exp=1`. En ese caso no entraba por el `else` y por tanto el único `return` que encontraba era el `return 0` del final. Así que según tu funcióin, cualquier número elevado a 1 debería dar 0. Ese 0 se propagaba al multiplicar potencias superiores, y así todas dan cero. Obviamente el caso en que `exp=1` debías retornar la propia base en vez de 0.

Comment: Así que otra posible implementación sería `if (exp==1) return base; else return base*potencia(base, (exp-1));`

Answer (score 0):

lo que buscas es multiplicar la 'base' 'exp' veces, aquí debes identificar cual es la operación o conjunto de operaciones que se repiten, en este caso es la multiplicación

```
2^3 = 2 * 2 * 2
```

Toda función recursiva consta basicamente de dos elementos, el algoritmo que se replica n veces y una condición de finalización.

En este caso la multiplicación de la base es la operación iterativa y el exponente marca la condición de finalización.

```
resultado = base * potencia(exp - 1, base) * potencia(exp - 2, base)...
```

Esto nos daria

```
public static int potencia(int exp, int base) {
    return base * potencia(exp - 1, base); 
}
```

Recuerda que es importante siempre la condición de finalización, de lo contrario caería en un bucle infinito, la condición de finalización es cuando el exponente llega a 1

```
public static int potencia(int exp, int base) {
    if (exp == 1) {
        return base;
    } else {
        return base * potencia(exp - 1, base); 
    }
}
```

El resultado

```
------------------------------------------------------
    Programa que calcula la potencia de un numero
------------------------------------------------------
Introduzca la base: 2
Introduzca el exponente: 4
La potencia de 2 elevado a 4 es: 16
```